# Fix Custom Taxonomy Display two times on each call

Tags: custom-taxonomy

```
<p> <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'sublocation');
    if ($terms) {
       foreach ($terms as $term) {
       $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'sublocation') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
       }
    echo join( ', ', $out );
    } ?>
</p>


 <p>TYPE OF MUSIC: <?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'music'); 
      if ($terms) { foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'music') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
      } echo join( ', ', $out ); 
      }?>
</p>

<p>TYPE OF PUB: <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'pub');
      if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
       foreach ($terms as $term) {
         $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'pub') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
       }
        echo join( ' ', $out );
       } ?>
</p>
```

After calling this i am getting like this

[image]

See above image the categories are showing same on each type.

Please how can i fix this

Comment: Isn't this the same question as this one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/113333/21376 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p> <?php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms ( $post -> ID , 'sublocation' ) ;
if ( $terms ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $out[ ] = '<a class="' . $term -> slug . '" href="' . get_term_link ( $term -> slug , 'sublocation' ) . '">' . $term -> name . '</a>' ;
    }
    echo join ( ', ' , $out ) ;
}
?>
</p>

<p>TYPE OF MUSIC: <?php
    $terms = get_the_terms ( $post -> ID , 'music' ) ;
    if ( $terms ) {
        $out = array ( ) ; // reInitialise
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $out[ ] = '<a class="' . $term -> slug . '" href="' . get_term_link ( $term -> slug , 'music' ) . '">' . $term -> name . '</a>' ;
        }
        echo join ( ', ' , $out ) ;
    }
?>
</p>

<p>TYPE OF PUB: <?php
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms ( $post -> ID , 'pub' ) ;
    if ( ! empty ( $terms ) ) {
        $out = array ( ) ; // reInitialise
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $out[ ] = '<a class="' . $term -> slug . '" href="' . get_term_link ( $term -> slug , 'pub' ) . '">' . $term -> name . '</a>' ;
        }
        echo join ( ' ' , $out ) ;
    }
?>
</p>
```